# exo-desktop-item-edit parameters for command

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, .desktop

I created a desktop launcher for `exo-desktop-item-edit` with this command:

```
exo-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/.local/share/applications
```

However, when starting the launcher to create a new launcher, it is asking for a filename / location when saving.

Seems like the `--create-new ~/.local/share/applications` parameter is ignored when being run as launcher command while it works fine from the command line.

This is the `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Create Launcher
Comment=
Exec=exo-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/.local/share/applications
Icon=applications-other
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

Comment: AFAIK shell constructs like `~` are not supported in a .desktop file Exec key - you'll likely need to either replace it with a literal path or wrap the whole command line in a `sh -c ' ... '`

Comment: Thanks, using an absolute path (not sure what "literal path" means) fixed it.

Comment: Haha I couldn't think of a better term than "literal" since arguably `~/` is itself an absolute path - or, at least, isn't a relative path - see for example [Is `~/Documents` a relative or an absolute path?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/221970/is-documents-a-relative-or-an-absolute-path)